# How can I plot this?

Tags: matlab, regression

Doing a little machine learning, and working on some linear regression.  I can't seem to plot this in Matlab.

Given a bunch of data

[image]

how do I plot

[image]

in matlab?  I know it should be parabolic, but my code (shown below) doesn't give me a `paraboloid`.

```
x=linspace(0,1,1001);
M=numel(x);

y=2*x-3+(-2+4*rand());

plot(x,y)

[theta1,theta2]=meshgrid(0:0.01:3,-5:0.01:-2);

J=zeros(length(theta1),length(theta2));

for i = 1:M

     J=J+(theta1*x(i)-theta2-y(i)).^2;

 end

 J=(2*M)^(-1)*J;

 mesh(theta1,theta2,J)
```

Comment: Why do you have the line `J=(2*M)^(-1)*J;`? It seems you need `J=J/(2*M);` - not sure where these negative powers are coming from; they aren't in your expression?

Comment: @Floris Those two statements are synonymous. Notice the `(2*M)^(-1)=(1/(2*M))`. Try [this resource](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/negative-exponents.html)

Comment: Might be a typo but in your code you have `theat2-y(i)` but in the equation above it looks like it should be `theta2*y(i)`. However I ran this and it still does not produce a parabaloid.

Answer (score 1):

There are two very minor problems with your code:

Number 1: Within the sum it should be `theta2*y(i)`.

Number 2: Your range is too small to see the paraboloid shape! Try running the example below:

```
x=linspace(0,1,1001);
M=numel(x);

y=2*x-3+(-2+4*rand());

plot(x,y)

[theta1,theta2]=meshgrid(-20:1:20,-20:1:20);

J=zeros(size(theta1));

for i = 1:M

     J=J+(theta1*x(i)-theta2*y(i)).^2;

 end

 J=(2*M)^(-1)*J;
figure(1);
 mesh(theta1,theta2,J)
 xlabel('\theta_1');
 ylabel('\theta_2');
```

Which produces:

[image: Paraboloid Output]